# Manipulating view hierarchy by code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

If I have a `UITabBarController` (2 tabs) as root view controller then in the first tab (`FirstTabViewController`) I init a `UINavigationController` with a root view controller `AddReminderViewController` and present it.

Then inside `AddReminderViewController` I present another `UINavigationController` with a root view controller called `ChooseOptionViewController` and present it.

Now when I'm inside `ChooseOptionViewController` I want to programtically go back to `FirstTabViewController` how can I do this as easy as possible? Do I need to `- dismissViewController...` on all view controllers that I have presented or is there an easier way?

Also inside `ChooseOptionViewController` how can I find out the class that presented `ChooseOptionViewController`? I tried doing `[self.presentingViewController class]` but that just says `UINavigationController` (not `AddReminderViewController`)

Comment: Why are you creating a second navigation controller? You can just push all viewcontrollers on the first navigationcontroller.

Comment: @Marcel it was a design decision taken a while back ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now when I'm inside ChooseOptionViewController I want to
>   programtically go back to FirstTabViewController how can I do this as
>   easy as possible?

You really ought not to have the ChooseOptionViewController try to manage all that by itself. It should simply tell its parent that its job is done and let the parent dismiss it. The parent could then tell its parent that its job is done, and so on. This approach will make it much easier to maintain your code, and to change things around when you decide that's necessary, without breaking ChooseOptionViewController.

For example, imagine that AddReminderViewController wants something else to happen, like presenting ChooseMoreOptionsViewController after ChooseOptionsViewController has been presented. If AddReminderViewController is in charge of the flow of its part of the program, that's easy. If ChooseOptionsViewController knows enough about the reset of the app to dismiss view controllers all the way back to FirstTabViewController, you'll have to modify it every time there's a change in the flow. That's not a recipe for long term success, and it adds a lot of unnecessary and unhelpful complexity.

Comment: The normal flow is that the user interacts with the views, he can cancel (which will call `-dismiss...` on ChooseOptionViewController) and so on. However when the app is entering background I want the app to reset to the first tab.

Comment: @PeterWarbo In that case, you still want the parent view controllers to be in charge. One approach would be to have the app delegate or FirstTabViewController post a notification that other controllers, like AddReminderViewController, listen for. The notification would mean "okay, button up whatever you were doing and dismiss any modal view controllers. After that, FirstTabViewController can `popToRootViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

```
generally unless an exception you should use only one navigation controller.
keep pushing view controllers onto it.
in that way you can move pop top to root view controller.


for ex:

1
just add one navigation controller to tab 1

2
setrootviewcontroller of navigation controller to FirstTabViewController

3
from FirstTabViewController you can push AddReminderViewController(using the same navigation controller)
ex:- [self.navigationController PushViewController:....];

4
from AddReminderViewController you can push ChooseOptionViewController(using the same navigation controller)
ex:- [self.navigationController PushViewController:....];



5 finally use [self.navigationController popToRootViewController];
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It's possible to present a navigation controller modally, so that you can have a modal interaction that spans multiple view controllers. This is often more desirable than presenting one modal view controller on top of another on top of another...

Comment: ok sir...you need to take a reference of bottom most navigation controller and call popToRootViewController.

Comment: `-popToRootViewController` doesn't dismiss view controllers presented modally.